# Device to programmatically controlled USB relay/switch

Tags: usb, switches, relay, temperature, home-automation

(**Edited** to remove shopping question.  I don't need recommendation of a specific product as much as I would like to know what such a device would be called.)

---

I'm know more about programming than I do about electronics, and I'm looking for an inexpensive way to programmatically open/close a low voltage circuit.

I imagine there must be some sort of simple USB controllers; I'm probably just not using the right search terminology.

I'd have a few applications for such a device.  One example: I can already receive real-time household temperature & humidity data with a USB sensor like [this](http://www.ebay.ca/itm/322821357740).  I can collect and analyze that data in Windows (with VBA in a Microsoft Access database, for simplicity's sake), but I also want to open & close the low-voltage control circuit for my furnace, for both real-time temperature control, as well as analysis and experimentation.

What would a device like this be called? Expensive solutions would be counterproductive since the overall objective is to *save* money, not spend it!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You need to edit to remove the shopping question or your question will be closed. See [Don't ask](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Most home automation equipment is Ethernet or WiFi rather than USB.

Comment: I suggest you go to sites like instructables, look for similar projects  and see what they use.

Comment: Whats low cost for you? Easiest would be a board with an MCU and uart to usb converter, such as ST's Nucleo or some Arduinos.

Comment: Here are some Google keywords for you, if you use them right they should be able to keep you busy for weeks/months/years to come: DIY IOT "home automation" MQTT Zigbee relay MOSFET Arduino ESP8266 RaspberryPi "smart socket"

Comment: I reworded the question.  Thank you for the suggestions so far!

Comment: I think the keyword you are looking for is "relay", and the device you want is a "USB relay" - that is a device which connects through the USB port on a computer, and is used to open or close a circuit. Many of these will have delay timers, as that's an often-desired feature, but you don't need to use the timer. These are usually cheap. 

I am disappointed in the other commenters who either suggested you read the entirety of the Instructables website to find a single keyword, or who spent more time saying this should be closed than answering a question which should be simple for them.

Comment: As an addendum to my prior comment, an excellent rundown of relays is at https://ncd.io/relay-logic/ and that explains what the "NC" (normally closed) and "NO" (normally open) outputs mean, and it shows example setups. That site also has an extensive walkthrough of the more high-end and industrial focused considerations at https://ncd.io/choosing-the-right-usb-relay-controller/ which is good reading, but not necessary for simple first-time experiments like controlling an LED as you get your feet wet. Their relays are much more expensive than what you need; you can find plenty for around $10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be a Digital I/0 module from....

http://www.weedtech.com/digital-io.html

Works with windows, and you'd have ample ports left over.